# Quicktime for recording high quality audio?

Tags: audio-recording, software

First off, I'm completely new to sound recording, so pls excuse any dumb questions :)

I just ordered a Focusrite Solo Studio Package, so what I need to know is..

Given the high quality (sampling rate?) that this unit is capable of capturing, will I be limited by software also? I'd like to use quicktime for some screen recordings and voiceovers, but not sure if that would somehow be handicapping my new equiptment?

I have access to the bundled Focusrite software and also garageband etc. (using a mac) Would just be nice to capture my screen recordings and audio together and not have to sync them as 2 seperate files afterwards. Hence the reason I want to use quicktime.

Thanks in adavance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recording in Quicktime (via your Focusrite)should not be an issue and it doesn't hurt the quality of your recordings. Modern audio interfaces use Coreaudio and this works fine with quicktime .Check the apple and focusrite forums if you run into issues setting things up. It should be a breeze.